# How to get date modified of a file in cloud files?

Tags: c#, cloudfiles

How to get date modified of a file in cloud files?

I am using the .net SDK from cloud files (not the rack space nu get package).

I can get a list of my files and call GetStorageItemInformation size but I want to know when the file was put onto cloud files. If I use the Cloudberry explorer app I see it has the information.

Is it in the .net SDK and where?

Comment: Are you using the openstack.net package or the deprecated package csharp-cloudfiles?

Comment: Was using the older SDK, I think that was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the files in your container, you can use OpenStack.NET's ContainerObject.LastModified.  Here is a console application which lists all containers in a region and their files with the last modified timestamp.

```
using System;
using net.openstack.Core.Domain;
using net.openstack.Providers.Rackspace;

namespace CloudFilesDateModified
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string region = "DFW";
            var identity = new CloudIdentity { Username = "username", APIKey = "apikey" };

            var cloudfiles = new CloudFilesProvider(identity);
            foreach (Container container in cloudfiles.ListContainers(region:region))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Container: {container.Name}");

                foreach (ContainerObject file in cloudfiles.ListObjects(container.Name, region: region))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{file.Name} - {file.LastModified}");
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Below is some sample output

```
Container: test
    foobar - 10/12/2015 2:00:26 PM -06:00
    foobar/file.png - 11/6/2015 7:34:42 PM -06:00
    foobar/index.html - 11/6/2015 7:34:31 PM -06:00
```

If your container has more than 10,000 files, you will need to use the paging parameters to loop through all the files. In the example below, I am paging through the results 100 at a time.

```
foreach (Container container in cloudfiles.ListContainers(region: region))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Container: {container.Name}");

    int limit = 100;
    string lastFileName = null;
    IEnumerable<ContainerObject> results;
    do
    {
        results = cloudfiles.ListObjects(container.Name, region: region, limit: limit, marker: lastFileName);
        foreach (ContainerObject file in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\t{file.Name} - {file.LastModified}");
            lastFileName = file.Name;
        }
    } while (results.Any());
}
```

Comment: that's great. Is there an easy way to get ALL the files? The ListObjects appears to get the first 10,000.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include an example of how to page through the results when there are more than 10,000 files in a container.